# instantiate ArrayList that was declared as instance variable

Tags: java, arraylist

The ArrayList was declared as instance variable and then I instantiate it in the constructor. 
In addIt method I store Plus object that was passed as argument in the ArrayList.

Problem: not sure if I am doing instantiation in the constructor correctly.
Other thing I am not sure about is if in addIt method I store Plus object that was passed as argument in the ArrayList

This is my code I was working on and what I tried to do.

```
 
public class Test {
```

```
private ArrayList t;

public Test() {
    t = new ArrayList();
}

public void addIt(Plus p) {
    t.add(p);
}
```

}

Plus is an interface

Comment: Does it compile? Does it do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Using a raw type is seriously discouraged. What type of objects do you intend to put in it?

Comment: The instruction I wrote at the beginning are correct. The object is type Plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is perfectly fine to me.  It could stand to use generic types, for example to declare `private ArrayList t;` instead as `private ArrayList<Plus> t;` and then your constructor `t = new ArrayList<Plus>();` but this will work as-is.

There is nothing wrong with instantiating a member or instance variable within a constructor.